# Translate ASSEMBLY to C

Tags: assembly, c

How to translate code assembly to C?? I am very poor in assembly code. EG:

```
mov     dword ptr [ebp+data], 612E2F47h
mov     dword ptr [ebp+data+4], 5B2A451Ch
mov     dword ptr [ebp+data+8], 6E6B5E18h
mov     dword ptr [ebp+data+0Ch], 5C121F67h
mov     dword ptr [ebp+data+10h], 0D5E2223h
mov     dword ptr [ebp+data+14h], 5E0A5F1Dh
mov     word ptr [ebp+data+18h], 858h
mov     word ptr [ebp+data+1Ah], 0h
xor     eax, eax                
loc_4012B2:                             
add     [ebp+eax+data], al      
inc     eax                     
cmp     eax, 1Ah                
jl      short loc_4012B2
```

Comment: -2 down vote favorite?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675326/translate-assembly-to-c

Comment: Reverse engineering isn't about converting assembly to C, it's about understanding what's going on.

Comment: These days it is possible to ask ChatGPT or related models to explain and translate these instructions to C or even to Python. The result here is "G00d J0b guys, k33p 1t up!\x1a\x1b" :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is exact answer to you question.

1. Go to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_assembly_online.php
2. Doubleclick on main.asm in upper-left corner of the screen
3. Copy your snippet to the text window. You'll need to add definition of data and make some tweaks, my resulting assembly code is

   ```
   section     .text
   global main
   main:

   xor ebp,ebp

   mov      dword [ebp+data], 0x612E2F47
   mov      dword [ebp+data+4], 0x5B2A451C
   mov      dword [ebp+data+8], 0x6E6B5E18
   mov      dword [ebp+data+0Ch], 0x5C121F67
   mov      dword [ebp+data+10h], 0x0D5E2223
   mov      dword [ebp+data+14h], 0x5E0A5F1D 
   mov      dword [ebp+data+18h], 0x858
   mov      dword [ebp+data+1Ah], 0x0
   xor     eax, eax                
   loc_4012B2:                             
   add     [ebp+eax+data], al      
   inc     eax                     
   cmp     eax, 1Ah                
   jl      short loc_4012B2
   nop
   nop


   section     .data

   data    db 0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0
   ```
4. Press compile button
5. Go to project menu, download the project, extract `demo` file from the archive
6. Go to [retdec decompiler site](https://retdec.com/decompilation/)
7. Select executable input file and upload your binary file there
8. Press decompile
9. See results

I wouldn't say that results of this translation to C code are too much understandable.
In addition I'd like to note that learning 6 assembly commands is much less time consuming process.

Comment: and, of course, http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems