# Automatic decompilation from Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, decompilation, disassemblers, decompile, decompiler

Is there a tool to automatic decompile an assembly x86 code?

What I need is a tool where I simply paste my code and it returns C code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "automatic", but you could always *assemble* your code, then run it through a decompiler to get your pseudocode C output. [This answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/10925) details a way to do this entirely from the browser.